# Using javascript to copy "td" element to clipboard without button, but display what has been copied to user with timeout

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, firstly I need to own up to having no JavaScript coding experience. So I am going cap in hand for some help on this please.

I would like the user of a webpage to be able to click on a value contained within a table ('td') and for it to be copied to the clipboard. So that the user knows that this has happened, I'd like a message to appear briefly letting them know that they have copied something and what that was.

Hopefully this makes sense?

I have found the following code (apologies for not remembering where) which copies the value to the clipboard okay, but this is where I am stuck and cannot get the tooltip part going.

Hoping that somebody can enlighten me!

**Code Snippet**

```js
function copy(event) {
  console.log("Triggered")
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  console.log("Targeted", target)
  var copyText = target.innerText || target.textContent;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText)

  // select the cell
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(target);
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
}

document.querySelectorAll("td")
  .forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("click", copy))
```

```css
td {
  border: thin solid gray;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr>
<tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
<tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function copy(event) {
  console.log("Triggered")
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  console.log("Targeted", target)
  var copyText = target.innerText || target.textContent;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText)

  // select the cell
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(target);
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.textContent = 'Copied to clipboard!'
  div.className = 'tooltip'
  console.log(event.target.clientY)
  const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect()
  console.log(rect)
  div.style.top = Math.floor(rect.top) + 'px'
  div.style.left = Math.floor(rect.left) + 'px'
  document.body.appendChild(div)
  setTimeout(() => div.remove(), 2000)
}

document.querySelectorAll("td")
  .forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("click", copy))
```

```css
td {
  border: thin solid gray;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr>
<tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
<tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks exactly like the result I'm after, thank you. The only issue is that it doesn't seem to be working for me on my table.

As I'm new to stackoverflow, I'm not sure how to add the html I have for my table.

Answer (score 0):

After painstakingly going through my code, I found out that one bit of CSS was causing the issue and making the tooltip not show.

I am using bootstrap and the solution to make it work as per Konrad's excellent solution is to add

```
opacity: inherit;
```

to the tooltip CSS.

I also changed a couple of other lines of CSS which seems to make it even better

```
position: fixed;
  translate: 50% -10%;
```

Thanks again, Konrad!